# Is there a way to check whether chi-square or Fisher's exact test should be used and then run it automatically?

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared, statistical-test

I am new to R, but I turned to it as it is the only software available to me that can perform Fisher's exact text on tables bigger than 2x2.

In theory '**the chi-square test is performed only if at least 80% of the cells have an expected frequency of 5 or greater, and no cell has an expected frequency smaller than 1.**'

I often have to run multiple analyses, for hundreds of tables, some of which meet the criteria for chi-square, while for some the Fisher's test should be used.

I know how to do it by hand, by generating contingency table, looking at it, counting whether I should use chi-square of Fisher's test, and then running the test with chisq.test()/fisher.test().

Is there any way to automate this process? some **way to automate and squeeze the checking process into a single command, and depending on its output automatically perform chi-square or Fisher's test**?

I hope I made myself clear, thanks to everyone who read it :)

Comment: Seems like you already have some criteria for selecting the test, then a simple `if/else` statement should do the job (maybe together with `apply` function to iterate over your data)

Comment: To answer your question, yes there's a way. However, it would be easier to provide you with a how-to if you could provide a reproducible data set and an expected outcome.

Comment: @Phil So here is a dummy set of data (https://pastebin.com/Fi6ERaim), gender (m/f), whether they have neflix (y/n) and guns (y/n). I would like to run a loop that would go through a set of variables and perform chi/fisher of gender vs variables in the loop depending on the data (in this case: netflix should go with chi, guns with fisher)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function:

```
myfun <- function(data, var1, var2, chi = TRUE) {
  t <- table(data[[var1]], data[[var2]])

  if (chi) {
    chisq.test(t)
  } else {
    fisher.test(t)
  }
}
```

And then apply it as you see fit:

```
myfun(dat, "gender", "netflix")

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  t
X-squared = 0, df = 1, p-value = 1

myfun(dat, "gender", "guns", chi = FALSE)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  t
p-value = 0.0003284
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   2.867735 118.989345
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  15.45796
```